# How to delete uri directory(Folder) after user picks folder?

Tags: java, directory, uri

I have a notepad app that restores notes and backs them up. When manually backing up, it usually on android 10 would delete the folder then create it again with new files. Now with saf i cant figure out how to delete a chosen tree folder.
Heres my code but it doesnt work.

```
try {
muri = t.getString("muri", "");
Uri uri = Uri.parse(muri);
DocumentsContract.deleteDocument
(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
}  catch (Exception e) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

```
try {
muri = t.getString("muri", "");
Uri uri = Uri.parse(muri);
DocumentFile dir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, uri);
DocumentFile dir2 = dir.findFile("Godisgood");
dir2.delete();
}  catch (Exception e) {}
```